# Question on AsymptoticDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, asymptotics

I would like to use `AsymptoticDSolveValue` to solve following type of equations at infinity

```
y''[x] + (1 - 1/x^s) y[x] == 0
```

where s are positive rational numbers.
The result is obvious,

```
E^(-I x)  C[1] + E^(I x)  C[2]
```

for the leading order.

For any integer s
`AsymptoticDSolveValue` provides a solution which is the same with intuitive result; but for
non-integer s,
`AsymptoticDSolveValue` can not give a solution. What's the problem here? Why does not `AsymptoticDSolveValue` work?

Comment: What's your code using `AsymptoticDSolveValue`?

Comment: Are there any particular non-integer values of `s` that you are interested in?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, say for s=3/2, AsymptoticDSolveValue[(1 - 1/x^(3/2)) y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    x] == 0, y[x], {x, \[Infinity], 1}].

Comment: @CarlWoll, no, I am more interested in the general algorithm.

Comment: I think it's possible to transform the ODE so that a result can be obtained for any particular rational value of `s`. But this doesn't constitute a general algorithm.

Comment: @CarlWoll, yes, thanks. It may work, if I perform a transformation at first, so that there is only integer power of x in the equation.

Comment: @user142288 `AsymptoticDSolveValue` doesn't evaluate the case `s=3/2`